# import data from CSV into a Postgres table using pgAdmin 3

Tags: python, database, postgresql, csv, import

```
COPY des_unificado (cedula, grupo, nivel, insti, sector, dpto, zona, ccorres, apel_corto, digito_id, nombre, cargo, pres_act, turno, tipo_rubro, catego_psp, cant_rubro, presupuesto_ant, devenga_ant, aporte_ips, aporte_bnt, ac_meses, ac_aguinal, f_mm_ing_c, f_aa_ing_c, opera_lqd, tipo_rgtro, status_crg, aa_plan, mm_plan, jubilac, rec_ant, ccorr, orden, antece_nro, resolu_nro, estado, insti_ant, id_grado_c, seccion, id_especia, multa, judicial, afemec, otros_dec, presupuesto, afemec_1, liquido, dcto_jub, monto_defi, aux, linea)
FROM '/home/arturo/Escritorio/des_unificado1.csv' 
WITH DELIMITER ';'
CSV HEADER
```

**Can someone help me, when you run these commands, I get the following error:**

```
ERROR:  could not open file "/home/arturo/Escritorio/des_unificado1.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
```

********** Error **********

```
ERROR: could not open file "/home/arturo/Escritorio/des_unificado1.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
```

Comment: As the error suggests, did you see if `/home/arturo/Escritorio/des_unificado1.csv` indeed exists ? verify the file does exist by doing `ls /home/arturo/Escritorio/des_unificado1.csv`

Comment: You need to include more information -- what user are you running the command as, what machine are you running the command on, what machine is postgres running on, what are the permissions, owner and group of the file you are trying to import?

Comment: tells me not existeel file, but if I have it on the desktop @karthikr

Comment: @EdKing can you help me, I need so much an answer

Comment: if it tells you file does not exist, you need to address that first. Are you trying to copy _from_ the database or _to_ the database ?

Comment: I'm trying to copy from the database @karthikr

Comment: I'm trying to copy a table from dbf_unificado.csv to dbf_unificado @karthikr

Comment: If you are trying to read from a file that does not exist, what makes you think it would work ? Please update the file path with a valid one

Comment: I do not know that when I give you right click on properties it shows me this following address '/home/arturo/Escritorio/des_unificado1.csv' @karthikr

Comment: If the file is on your desktop, where is the postgres server?  If it is not running on your desktop, that could be an issue (hence the questions -- what user are you running the command as, what machine are you running the command on, what machine is postgres running on, what are the permissions, owner and group of the file you are trying to import?).  Sorry I didn't see this sooner -- was out of the office the last 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

`COPY` expects the file to be on the database *server*, not the database *client*. So if you're connecting to a server on a different computer and the file is on your computer, the file doesn't exist for the server.

If you want the file to be on the database client, you can use the `psql` command `\copy`. See `\?` for details.

This is a part of the `psql` command line client, not the server. Internally it uses `COPY ... FROM STDIN` and reads the file then sends it to the server over the PostgreSQL connection.

Comment: @Matias Use `\copy` in `psql`.

Comment: Can you give me your email, I want to send a screenshot @karthikr please

Comment: Can you give me your email, I want to send a screenshot @craig-ringer please

Comment: You can just paste a link to an upload of the image.

Comment: @Matias You do not appear to be listening. Your screenshot shows that you are using `COPY` via pgadmin. Use `\copy` in `psql`. If you are using pgadmin you do not have `\copy`. You must instead use pgadmin's "import" command, or use the `psql` command-line client.

Comment: @Matias but... It's the same command, just `\copy` instead of `copy` and it only works in `psql`. Or you can use the gui import tool in pgadmin which does copy.

Comment: I can't do it friends